# CSS first GENERATION div but not second selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to match the first generation division elements (all of them) but NOT any of THEIR children. So if I used the selector to apply a border 1 (as below visually) would gain the container however 2 (as below visually) would NOT gain the container. How do I construct that selector please?

```
<div id="container">
<div>1<div>2</div></div>
<div>1<div>2</div></div>
<div>1<div>2</div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: although there are some ways to do it, the best crossbrowser way to do it is to use classes

Comment: @Ibu I presume you are talking about the direct child selector (`>`)? Do you know which browsers don't support it, by any chance? I thought it was pretty ubiquitous.

Comment: @GregL: IE 6 doesn't support the `>` selector. http://caniuse.com/#search=%3E

Comment: @Guffa So < ~3% in most non-Asian countries? http://www.ie6countdown.com/. I am increasingly not overly concerning myself with the tiny minority of people still using IE6. You?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
#container > div {
   border: 1px solid #f0f;
}
```

Comment: Not allowed to answer my own post... >__>

Comment: Yes, this is what I found in my own code from a couple months ago, thanks!

Comment: Can't vote up because of artificial time limits, will later. >__>

Answer (score 1):

The best way is using the immediate [child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors) (`>`):

```
#container > div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

(IE6 does not support this)

Answer (score 1):

The selector for that is:

```
div#container > div
```

or just

```
#container > div
```

I really like the [SelectORacle](http://tux.theopalgroup.com/cgi-bin/css3explainer/selectoracle.py) to help understand CSS selectors. More on [Child Selectors](http://meyerweb.com/eric/articles/webrev/200006b.html) from Eric Meyer.

**UPDATE FOR Microsoft Internet Explorer 6**

If support for `>` is a concern, as in the case of MSIE6, the traditional way I used to handle it was to set the styles for the first generation, then unset them for every other descendent generation. So, like this:

```
#container div { border: 1px solid #000; }
#container div div { border: none; }
#container div div div { border: none; }
#container div div div div { border: none; }
```

You do that with as many generations down as you need to do. In the above I allow 3 more levels of nesting (enough?) It is not pretty, but it is reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Since one browser in particular (IE6) does not support the [child selector `>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors), you could use [descendent selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors) instead to add a border to the first descendant and remove it from the descendent's descendent.

#### HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div>1
       <div>2</div>
    </div>
    <div>1
        <div>2</div>
    </div>
    <div>1
        <div>2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#container div {
    border:1px dashed grey;
}

#container div div {
    border:none;
}
```

If IE6 is a browser you do need to support then the `>` selector as already answered is the simplest way to style the child.